# c++ matrix insert value using iterators (homework)

Tags: c++, matrix, iterator

I'm pretty new to C++ and got an assignment to make a matrix using only STL containers. I've used a vector (rows) of vectors (columns). The problem I'm having is in the 'write' operation - for which I may only use an iterator-based implementation. Problem is, quite simply: it writes nothing.

I've tested with a matrix filled with different values, and while the iterator ends up on exactly the right spot, it doesn't change the value.

Here's my code:

```
void write(matrix mat, int row, int col, int input)
{
    assert(row>=0 && col>=0);
    assert(row<=mat.R && col<=mat.C);

    //I set up the iterators.
    vector<vector<int> >::iterator rowit;
    vector<int>::iterator colit;
    rowit = mat.rows.begin();

    //I go to the row.
    for(int i = 0; i<row-1; ++i)
    {   
        ++rowit;
    }

    colit = rowit->begin();

    //I go to the column.
    for(int j = 0; j<col-1; ++j)
    {
        ++colit;
    }

    *colit = input; //Does nothing.
}
```

What am I overlooking?
Thanks.

Comment: What is this function supposed to do?

Comment: @DavidBrown: What do you think? It's called `write` and the code is quite clear.

Comment: @ David Brown Change the value at the place of the iterator with the 'input' value.

Comment: Make `write` a member function of your `matrix` type (and rename that type to `Matrix`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matrix mat` is a parameter by value, it copies the matrix and hence you are writing to a copy.

You should pass the matrix by reference instead, like `matrix & mat`.

---

**But wait...** You are passing the matrix every time as the first parameter, this is a bad sign!

This usually indicates that the parameter should be turned into an object on which you can run the methods; that way, you don't need to pass the parameter at all. So, create a `Matrix` class instead.

---

Please note that there is [std::vector::operator[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at).

So, you could just do it like this:

```
void write(matrix & mat, int row, int col, int input)
{
    assert(row>=0 && col>=0);
    assert(row<=mat.R && col<=mat.C);

    mat[row][col] = input;
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a ton, solved already! :)
How could I overlook such a simple thing?

--
EDIT:On the classes thing. I actually wanted to use a class, and it'd be much easier that way, but we aren't supposed to use classes yet (hehe), so I used a struct instead.
Again, thanks!

Comment: @AntoonJuliaan: See my update, a single operator function makes this much easier for you. ;)

Comment: I know and that's what I wanted to do in the first place, but our assignment said explicitly to use iterators. :/

Comment: @AntoonJuliaan: Okay, then use `*(mat.begin().advance(row - 1).begin().advance(col - 1)) = input;`! ;)

Comment: Damn, that's clever. Thanks again, this is becoming quite a learning experience. :)